# ORder a list based on a parent Id within the list

Tags: c#, list

I have the following list of objects, having an Id and in some cases, a parent ID value:

```
({751, null}, {752, 0}, {753, 751}, {754, null}, {755, 754}, {756, 0})
```

What I want to do is order the list first by the Id in ascending order, and then group those having the parent ID equal to the Id next to each other.

So the rendered list should be as below:

```
({751, null}, {753, 751}, {752, 0}, {754, null}, {755, 754}, {756, 0})
```

Any idea of how to do this from a list?

Comment: list.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ThenBy(x => x.ParentId) solve this your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve it by using:

```
var result = list
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .GroupBy(x => (x.ParentId == 0 || x.ParentId == null ? null : x.ParentId) ?? x.Id)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

First, order by id. Then group the items by parent id (if it has a parent id and it is not null), else by id. Lastly, flatten the grouped list by `SelectMany(x => x)`.

Comment: the rendered list of your answer is : ({751, null}, {752, 0}, {753, 751}, {754, null}, {755, 754}, {756, 0}).  I need it to be ({751, null}, {753, 751}, {752, 0}, {754, null}, {755, 754}, {756, 0}). Thanks

Comment: @refresh No, it is not. It is ({751, null}, {753, 751}, {752, 0}, {754, null}, {755, 754}, {756, 0}), just as you asked.

Comment: I had to do it twice.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8)

```
var myOrderedList = myDisordedList.OrderBy(i=> i.parentId);
```

Comment: The rendered list for your given answer is :({751, null}, {754, null}, {752, 0}, {756, 0}, {753, 751}, {755, 754}).